# How to catch status code 409 in angular that connects keycloak?

Tags: angular, keycloak

i have angular app that connects to keycloak that register user. If username or email already exists it sends ..

[image]

instead of this error i wanna catch this error and send some alert that says email or username already exists kind of message

```js
try {
  axios
    .post("http://0.0.0.0:8083/", user)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Registration successful:", response.data);
      this.message.success("Registration successful");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Registration failed:", error);
      this.message.error("Registration failed");
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Keycloak user registration failed:", error);
  this.message.error("Keycloak user registration failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can special handling for [`409 Conflict`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) by Axios return [status checking](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

```
The HTTP 409 Conflict response status code indicates a request conflict with the current state of the target resource.

Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, you may get a 409 response when uploading a file that is older than the existing one on the server, resulting in a version control conflict.
```

This value can filter for special handling.

```
error.response.status -> 409
```

In the keycloak, it can be arias 409 error duplicated user when add a new user.

This demo code to emulate Keyclok 409 error by Flask server.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
PORT = 8083

@app.route("/user", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        return json, 409
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = PORT)
```

This `client.js` simulate your Angular API service

```
const axios = require("axios");
const jsonObj = {
    "user": "monkey",
    "password": "strong_password1234"
};

const addUser = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            url = 'http://localhost:8083/user',
            data = jsonObj,
            config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
        return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle Error Here
        return Promise.reject(error.response)
    }
};

addUser()
    .then((token) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(token, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        switch(error.status) {
            case 409:
                console.log('special handling: ' + error.status)
              break;
            default:
                console.log(error)
        }
    });
```

## Run server

```
python server.py
```

[image]

#Run client

```
node client.js
```

[image]

So you can handling whatever you want to handle it for 409 error by switch statments.